# Test Automation - Katalon - upload file when it's scanned for viruses

Tags: file-upload, katalon-studio

I was trying to upload a file from my local to the web page. I’m able to select the file using the Robot class, but I’m stuck on a part. When it uploads the file, I see a message in UI that the file is in “scanning for viruses”. But, it doesn’t complete. And I can’t move forward because the file upload is not complete as it’s still being scanned for viruses. (Screenshot attached)

However, in my application, when I open a session manually and upload a file manually, it’s being scanned for say max 2-3 seconds and after that, I see the upload is complete. Only, when the session is opened by Katalon, I’m not able to complete the upload as it gets stuck on scanning.

Can you please help me figure out why would it behave differently when done from an automated script as compared to a manual execution? Is it something related to browser settings when Katalon opens it? And how to handle this part in an automated script?

Please have a look at this. Looking forward to a reply.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwmW9.png)

Comment: What did you already try? Please share your code. Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?}(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hey, it's good now. I ran the script in incognito mode in chrome and it worked fine with the upload. May be something with cookies or cache while running normally could be the issue.